# haproxy transparent mode on 14.04

Tags: ssh, haproxy, transparent-proxy

As per my previous question [SSHD real-ip behind haproxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/620703/sshd-real-ip-behind-haproxy)
 - I'm now attempting to [setup HAProxy to transparently](http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/09/16/howto-transparent-proxying-and-binding-with-haproxy-and-aloha-load-balancer/) pass the IPs to the backend services.

tproxy modules loaded / and supported in haproxy (I recompiled haproxy with USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1);

```
~$ uname -r
3.13.0-34-generic

~$ lsmod | grep -ie tprox
xt_TPROXY              17356  0 
nf_defrag_ipv6         34768  2 xt_socket,xt_TPROXY
nf_defrag_ipv4         12758  2 xt_socket,xt_TPROXY
x_tables               34059  8 ip6table_filter,xt_mark,ip_tables,xt_socket,iptable_filter,xt_TPROXY,iptable_mangle,ip6_tables

~$ haproxy -vv
HA-Proxy version 1.5.3 2014/07/25
Copyright 2000-2014 Willy Tarreau <w@1wt.eu>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux2628
  CPU     = native
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -march=native -g -fno-strict-aliasing
  OPTIONS = USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_PCRE=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 8192, maxpollevents = 200

Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with zlib version : 1.2.8
Compression algorithms supported : identity, deflate, gzip
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports prefer-server-ciphers : yes
Built with PCRE version : 8.31 2012-07-06
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
```

server configuration;

```
~$ cat haproxy-iptables.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
sudo iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
sudo iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 111
sudo iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
sudo ip rule add fwmark 111 lookup 100
sudo ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
sudo ip route flush cache

~$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter=0

~$ cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
frontend public
    mode tcp

    bind :80
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

    bind :443 ssl crt example.pem no-tls-tickets

    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if HTTP

    use_backend ssh if { ssl_fc_sni ssh.example.com }

backend ssh
        mode tcp
        source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
        server ssh 127.0.0.1:22
        timeout server 2h

~$ tail -f /var/log/haproxy.log
Aug 18 16:07:44 localhost haproxy[3323]: 203.000.000.000:56914 [18/Aug/2014:16:07:24.233] public~ ssh/ssh 71/-1/20076 0 sC 0/0/0/0/3 0/0
```

without the `source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip` line in haproxy.cfg I get output in `/var/log/auth.log`

```
Aug 18 16:20:23 localhost sshd[6532]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Aug 18 16:20:23 localhost sshd[6532]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Aug 18 16:20:23 localhost sshd[6532]: debug1: Connection refused by tcp wrapper
Aug 18 16:20:23 localhost sshd[6532]: refused connect from localhost (127.0.0.1)
```

when the line is added to the ssh backend block, nothing is logged in `auth.log` - the packets are not hitting sshd (they still are listed in `haproxy.log`)

I gather it's probably related to the net.ipv4 settings?

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to use TPROXY, your SSH server must use the haproxy box as router (well, the haproxy box must be in the way of the packets, but this is the easiest way to do it).

You also need the send_redirects kernel parameter enabled:

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/send_redirects
```

Comment: Good call. This is begging the question, anyway. **Why** ssh through HTTPS - are you evading a corporate firewall? There are easier ways for this. Next up is **why** run HAproxy on the same box as the SSH server? It would likely work out of the box if HAproxy ran on the router, as Florin advises.

Comment: it's proxying to several services bound to localhost and providing auth for them, and yes I'm behind a firewall which blocks non-ssl traffic on 443

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [mmproxy](https://github.com/cloudflare/mmproxy), that proved the easiest way for me to set this up. It's transparent for the particular daemon,