# TPROXY Not working with HAProxy, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, iptables, haproxy, transparent-proxy

I'm trying to use HAProxy as a fully transparent proxy using TPROXY in Ubuntu 14.04. HAProxy will be setup on the first server with `eth0` `111.111.250.250` and `eth1` `10.111.128.134`. The single balanced server has `eth1` and `eth0` as well. `eth0` is the public facing network interface while `eth1` is for the private network which both servers are in.

**Problem:** I'm able to connect to the balanced server's port 1234 directly (via `eth1`) but am not able to reach the balanced server via Haproxy port 1234 (which redirects to 1234 via `eth0`). Am I missing out something in this configuration?

*Removing the line `source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip` from `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`, the haproxy works but not transparently.*

---

**On the HAProxy server**

The current kernel is `3.13.0-24-generic`. `iptables v1.4.21` is used, which I assume supports TPROXY but am not sure how to check.

The kernel appears to have TPROXY support:

```
# grep TPROXY /boot/config-3.13.0-24-generic 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY=m
```

HAProxy was compiled with TPROXY support:

```
haproxy -vv
HA-Proxy version 1.5.3 2014/07/25
Copyright 2000-2014 Willy Tarreau <w@1wt.eu>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux26
  CPU     = x86_64
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -g -fno-strict-aliasing
  OPTIONS = USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_LIBCRYPT=1 USE_STATIC_PCRE=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 8192, maxpollevents = 200

Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built without zlib support (USE_ZLIB not set)
Compression algorithms supported : identity
Built without OpenSSL support (USE_OPENSSL not set)
Built with PCRE version : 8.31 2012-07-06
PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
```

In `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`, I've configured a port to have the following options:

```
listen test1235 :1234
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance leastconn
    source 0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip

    server balanced1 10.111.163.76:1234 check inter 5s rise 2 fall 4 weight 4
```

The following `iptables` rules were added

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 111
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
ip rule add fwmark 111 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
sudo ip route flush cache
```

and

```
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

---

**On the balanced server**

In `/etc/networking/interfaces` I've set the gateway for `eth1` to be the HAProxy box `10.111.128.134` and restarted networking.

```
auto eth0 eth1
iface eth0 inet static
        address 111.111.250.250
        netmask 255.255.224.0
        gateway 111.131.224.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 209.244.0.3
iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.111.163.76
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 10.111.128.134
```

`ip route` gives:

```
default via 111.111.224.1 dev eth0 
10.111.0.0/16 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.111.163.76 
111.111.224.0/19 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 111.111.250.250
```

Comment: I believe I'm having the same problem in http://serverfault.com/questions/622111/haproxy-transparent-mode-on-14-04 I believe it's something to do with the routing, not able to find a lot of up-to-date info about it however :/

Comment: What's the indication of `tcpdump` on `eth1` on Server B? Are packets arriving? Do they have the correct source IP? Are replies emitted from the interface? If yes, do those appear on `eth1` of Server A?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue might be related to not having forwarding or nat rules but you need forward rules that direct traffic between eth0 <-> eth1.

ie:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 7601 packets, 661K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  18M   47G ACCEPT     all  --  eth1  eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  17M 2922M ACCEPT     all  --  eth0  eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Also one thing that has cough me offguard before was specify the interface device on the mangle table when I'm using multiple devices:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 35M packets, 50G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  59M   52G divert     tcp  --  eth1      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            socket
```

Where it eth1 should not be specify cause we're using eth0/eth1 or even bond0 & eth1.

Lastly you want to make sure you have natting rules ie:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1420K packets, 85M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1K  494M PUBLICSNAT     all  --  *      eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain PUBLICSNAT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out   source             destination         
1K  494M SNAT       all  --  *      eth1  10.1.1.0/24         0.0.0.0/0        to:8.8.8.8-8.8.8.10
 1K  336K RETURN     all  --  *      *     0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```